# pymssql | pymssql.pyx not found

Tags: python, pymssql

Importing **pymssql** fails resulting in the following error:

> Unable to open 'pymssql.pyx': File not found
>   (path_to_project_folder/src/pymssql.pyx).

I'm using python 3.6, Win10. The package was installed without errors to a separate anaconda environment.

What am I missing here?